# How to predict waiting time in a queuing system with heterogenous desks?

Tags: algorithm, queue

I have a system that modelizes a kind of queuing system, that is composed of these elements :

- services : a service that can be offered to a customer
- desks : a desk that can offer one or more services. There are several desks, and each can be configured to provide a different subset of services, with or without overlap between the desks
- customers/tickets : a customer comes in, and prints a ticket specifying which service she needs

The system is already in place and works fine. It is a real-world system, with tickets distributors that allow customers to request and print tickets, and desks client app to call customers to the desks, and displays to show the customers who goes where.

Now a new requirement is a way to approximately predict the waiting time for any given ticket in the queue, and raise an alarm if this waiting time gets too high.

We will have a service duration time that will be collected from usage statistics, for each service.

The prediction does not need to be very precise, the goal is to give the administrator of a site a quick outlook of the situation, a feedback whether everything is flowing smoothly, or if customers are accumulating in the queue and it would be good to open one more desk, or in the contrary, customers are scarce and a desk could be shut. The most important factor is the waiting time for the customers (for example it would be ok to have 10 customers waiting if each customers stays at the desk 1 minute, but not if this duration is 10 minutes!).

The problematic is that any desk can provide any service without limitations. So a given service can be provided by any number of desks. But in turn each desk can provide any number of services.

I tried various approaches :

You could generate a queue that consists exclusively of tickets for services that can be provided by one desk. But then, each ticket in this list might be "serviceable" by just this desk, or by 5 other desks too...

You could grab a ticket, see which desks are susceptible to service it, and grab all the tickets that can be serviced by any of these desks. Again the problem is that some tickets can be treated by only one desk in the set and others by all of them...

I really don't know how to tackle the problem from here. Are there any queuing models that can be used for that kind of heterogenous desks ? Any ideas how to modelize this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question with `algorithm`, and you are asking in a programming site (rather than a math or statistics site), I will approach this from a programming perspective.

Model:

```js
// creates a new ticket for a given service; arrival time and length are only known
// for generated tickets
class Ticket(int arrival, int length, Service s)

// an abstract distribution (parameters are distribution-dependent)
class Distribution(...) 
      int generate() // generates integer with this distribution

// a service, with a distributions of time-to-finish and time-between-arrivals 
//    (both set experimentally from historical data).
class Service(Distribution lengths, Distribution arrivals)
      // simulated ticket: length from lengths.generate(), 
      //     arrival from t + arrivals.generate();
      Ticket createFuture(int t)  
      // same as above, but arrival = t+0
      Ticket createNow(int t)

// a desk, offers one or more services
class Desk() 
      void addService(Service s) // allows this desk to attend this service
      void removeService(Service s) 
      bool isCompatible(Service s) // is this desk compatible with this service?
      void attend(Ticket t) // marks a desk as attending a service
      bool isFree() // returns true if the desk is not attending anyone
      // returns a finished ticket, if any. After this, isFree() will return true
      Ticket finished() 

// a policy which assigns tickets to desks. Implement your current one (probably "FIFO") 
class Policy()
      // returns a suitable desk for that ticket, or null if none is posible/desired
      Desk assign(Ticket t, Ticket[] pending, Desk[] deks) 

// a live queue of tickets, dispatched using policy p t
class Queue(int startTime, Policy p, Service[] ss, Desk[] ds)
      void push(Ticket t) // adds a new real ticket to the queue
      // estimates wait-times for new arrivals to all services at time 't'
      Map<Service, int> forecast(int t) 
      void tick() // advances time for this queue
      Queue clone(); // deep-clones the queue (including time, policy, desks, and services)
```

**Usage:**

1. define your services and model their arrival.
2. create desks and assign services to them.
3. define your current policy, create a queue with it. The queue will start out empty.
4. as time passes, call tick() (and, if tickets come in, use createNow() to push() them in)
5. call estimate() as required

**Implementation:**

tick() would iterate over all desks to see which have finished(), and assign tickets to desks according to current policy. By calling tick() several times until the queue is empty, the exact time-to-close can be determined for each service type -- but this destroys the queue, and it should be done only on clone()s of the current queue.

forecast() would clone() the queue N times, and for each cloned queue, advance the time 'now-t' times while adding simulated tickets (generated with createFuture()). You should chain the times of createFuture as follows:

```
// create 3 future tickets for service s
Ticket t1 = s.createFuture(now);
Ticket t2 = s.createFuture(t1.arrival);
Ticket t3 = s.createFuture(t2.arrival);
//...
```

simulated tickets would only be pushed into the actual queue once the simulated time reached their simulated arrival times. Once the simulated time reached 'now+t', the actual service latencies would be determined and averaged out over all N simulations, to yield the probabilistic forecast.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. We reached the same conclusion, i.e. to use some kind of simulation to predict actual waiting time. The details of implementation will vary slightly but some of the concepts you exposed will certainly come in handy.